# ObjC Firebase Dynamic Links only working through browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, deep-linking

I've setup Dynamic Links on the firebase console but they only work correctly if I go through the browser (eg Safari). When I click the url and it goes directly to the app it does not open the intended page.

Here's how I'm testing it (on a real device):

1. I pasted the short URL link from firebase to the notes app.
2. I did a long press and opened on Safari
   2.1 After the page loads I press "Open" and the app correctly launches on the desired page.
3. Then I went back to the Notes App, did a long press and selected "Open with App"

On this 3rd step the App does not launch on the desired page.

The reason is because when I launch on a browser it does a request to firebase and it returns the URL with all the parameters, but when it goes directly to the app it does not do the request.

Here's the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:
#if defined(__IPHONE_12_0) && (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_12_0)
(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#else
(nonnull void (^)(NSArray *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#endif  // __IPHONE_12_0

    BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL
                                                                completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink,
                                                                             NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                                    NSString *quickActionLinker = [Properties getStringValue:@"quickActionsLinker"];
                                                                    NSString *action = [dynamicLink.url absoluteString];
                                                                    [QuickActionsHandler handleQuickAction:quickActionLinker fromCode:[action componentsSeparatedByString:@"https://"][1] main:self.main];
                                                                }];      
    return handled;
}
```

When launching through the browser, dynamicLink.url returns a string, but when directly launching the app it returns nil.

Is there a way to do the request without going through a browser?